# Is it possible to host a Meteor.js application on HP Helion (or other OpenStack providers)?

Tags: meteor, cloud, hosting, openstack

My team and I are participating to a hackathon (hack4europe) that invites us to host our app on the HP Helion cloud platform.

HP Helion seems to be compatible with several technologies (including Node.js), and OpenStack-compliant, but I found no mention about Meteor.js...

Do you guys know if there is a way to upload and run a Meteor.js app on HP Helion? If so, do you have any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Modulus has a tool called demeteorize which should let you run it anywhere node is supported.

https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer

Comment: Also, meteor now lets you do a build which generates a node application tar.gz archive. Should run almost anywhere you can install node